# RubyMineでインデントの強制機能を切りたい

Tags: rubymine

### インデントが変な上にインデントを浅くできない

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16183
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17411
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16075

RubyMineですが、ERBのインデントがどうもおかしいです（8.0.3で修正されたところもあるようですがまだおかしい）。

Xcodeは、自動でついたインデントが深すぎた場合、手動で浅くする機能がありますが、
RubyMineは強制的にRubyMineの考える深さのインデント以上浅くすることができません。

#### インデントを浅くできない例

```
<div>
  <div>
    <%= 'aaaaa' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

という状態で`<%=`の前でDeleteキーを押すと、

```
<div>
  <div><%= 'aaaaa' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

となる。とくに`<%=`が入れ子状態だと異常に深いインデントが出現するため、浅くしたいができない。

#### インデントが変な例

```
<%= link_to hoge_path do -%>
    <i></i>
<% end -%>
```

なぜか、`<%=`や`<%`で囲むと中が4スペースになる（普通のHTMLで囲った場合は2スペース)。
「Reformat Code」したときもこの4スペースの箇所にもっていかれるので、「Reformat Code」することができない。

Tabs and Indentsで何を設定しても`%`での入れ子は4スペース...
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### インデントを切りたい

そこで、ERBの場合インデントさせないようにインデント自体の機能を切りたいです。
（インデントが浅くできない状況は`.rb`ファイルでも起こっています）

### RubyMineをアンインストールしなおしても改善せず

[ruby - How to Uninstall RubyMine? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297970/how-to-uninstall-rubymine)
リンク手順にしたがって、アンインストールして再インストールしても改善せず。
とはいえ、なぜか該当プロジェクトを再インストールしたRubyMineで開くと、開いていたファイル状態が記憶されているのとプロジェクトの構成をみるProjectペインが本来なら左端に出るのがデフォルトだがこれを右に移動した記憶が残っており、完全にアンインストールできていないもよう.....

### File Typesで認識をはずしてみた

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

File TypesからRHTMLに`*.erb`が設定されていましたので、`*.erb`を削除しました。
そうすると、RubyMineは`*.erb`はただのプレーンテキストだと認識しハイライトとインデント強制がなくなりました。

しかし理想はインデント強制のみを切りたいです。（`*.rb`でもインデントが手動で調整できないとチームと完全に一致させるのが困難)

Comment: 僕の環境では特に問題は起きていないです。erbファイルでも自由にインデントを変えられます。（RubyMineが強制的にインデントを変更したりしない）使用しているバージョンは8.0.3ですが、これまでRubyMineを使っていて違和感を感じたことはありませんでした。何かしら相性の悪いプラグインでも入っているのでしょうか？僕はIdeaVimとRailwaysを使っています。プラグインを全部OFFにしたり、ゼロからRailsプロジェクトを作成したりしても改善されませんか？

Comment: 既存ですでに入っているプラグインがたくさんありますが、PluginsでShow:Customで確認したところ、自分自身で入れたのは Css Alphabetical Rearranger, Railways, RuboCopの3つですが、すべて切りましたが、やはりインデントを浅くできませんでした。加えますと、このインデントが浅くできない状況はERBだけではなく.rbでも起こっています。

Comment: うーん、であれば経験がないのでちょっとわからないですね。。。ちなみにその現象はRubyMineを使い始めたときからですか？それとも特定のバージョン以降ですか？

Comment: Ruby7（詳しいマイナーバージョンまでは忘れてしまった）から使いだしたのですが、当初からインデントが浅くできない印象でした（思い違いの可能性もありますが）

Comment: インデントがおかしいときの具体的な例が抜けていたので追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※修正しました

恐らくMacで開発されていると思うのですが、その場合`delete`キーには`Backspace`が割り当てられています。`Backspace`ではインデントを削除しようとすると前の行に行ってしまいますが`Delete`コマンドが割り当てられたキーで削除すれば問題なく削除できました。

どのキーが`Delete`に割り当てられているかの確認は設定の`Keymap`を参照してください。

#### インデントが深くなりすぎてしまうこと自体への対策

`Preferences->Code Style->HTML->Other`にある`Do not indent children of:` で指定した要素の子要素はインデントがつかなくなり、また`or if tag size more than`で数値を指定すれば、その指定した行数以上タグの要素が続く場合はインデントされなくなります。

あとはご存知だとは思いますが、そんなにインデントが深くなるなら`partial`を作ってわけたほうが良いと思います。ただ、チームで開発してるとそれが難しい時もありますよね…。

Comment: 「deleteキーにはBackspace」Macでしたのでまさにその通りでした。
すみません。私の方でもっと詳細な例を挙げるべきでした。「インデントが変な例」の項目を追加しました。
Preferences->Code Style->HTML->Otherに`%=`を与えてみましたが4スペースインデントのままでした。（とはいえこの項目に`html`タグなどすでに与えられておりこれを削除することで`html`タグでもインデントするというチームの方針と合わせることができました。

Comment: タブ幅が4になってしまう件はIssueとして登録されてました。 一応、 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9092 File\Settings\Code Style\General(Tabs and Indents)\Other の設定を変えれば変更できるようです。

Comment: おお！このIssueは見落としてました！やっと2スペースになった！